# Jetpack proto datastore - gradle config with Kotlin dsl

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-jetpack-datastore

In jetpack datastore, you have to [set the gradle plugin task](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore#4) for generating class out of `.proto` files:

```
// build.gradle
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.10.0"
    }

    // Generates the java Protobuf-lite code for the Protobufs in this project. See
    // https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#customizing-protobuf-compilation
    // for more information.
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my project I use **Kotlin dsl** for my gradle project. After trying to convert this to kotlin dsl, `option` property is unknown and I can't find it's alternative for kotlin kts

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.10.0"
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option = "lite" // ** option is unknown **
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To use **Jetpack Proto Datastore** use the following code for **Gradle Kotlin DSL**

```kotlin
// top of file
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*

plugins {
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.12"
    // ...
}

val protobufVersion = "3.18.0"

dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:$protobufVersion")
  implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0-alpha03")
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:$protobufVersion"
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.plugins{
                create("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: works for me with latest versions end of 2022

Answer (score 5):

You can use builtins too.

```kotlin
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*


    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                id("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the difference between `task.plugins` and `task.builtins`?

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, the accepted answer put me on the right track but failed when syncing with the following error:

```
Unable to find method ''org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.NamedDomainObjectContainerExtensionsKt.invoke(org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1)''
'org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.NamedDomainObjectContainerExtensionsKt.invoke(org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1)'
```

So I replaced

```
task.plugins{
  create("java") {
    option("lite")
  }
}
```

with

```
task.plugins.create("java") {
  option("lite")
}
```

and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I met this error after updating to gradle 8

I found the solution here:[Proto datastore jetpack compose - gradle dependencies exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175068/proto-datastore-jetpack-compose-gradle-dependencies-exception).

just update the version of proto