# Proto datastore jetpack compose - gradle dependencies exception

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, protobuf-java, android-jetpack-datastore

I followed this codelab from the android developer platform: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore#4

Added the same exact dependencies as shown in the codelab and I get the following gradle exception when trying to sync

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

Could not get unknown property 'source' for generate-proto-generateDebugProto of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:125)
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'source' for generate-proto-generateDebugProto of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet.
  at com.google.protobuf.gradle.ProtobufPlugin$_linkGenerateProtoTasksToSourceCompile_closure25$_closure39.doCall(ProtobufPlugin.groovy:472)
  at com.google.protobuf.gradle.ProtobufPlugin$_linkGenerateProtoTasksToSourceCompile_closure25.doCall(ProtobufPlugin.groovy:469)
  at com.google.protobuf.gradle.ProtobufPlugin.linkGenerateProtoTasksToSourceCompile(ProtobufPlugin.groovy:468)
  at com.google.protobuf.gradle.ProtobufPlugin$_doApply_closure5.doCall(ProtobufPlugin.groovy:153)
  at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy56.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:125)
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
```

I have no idea what the issue could be, tried to upgrade the versions shown in the codelab, looked up the issue everywhere, but can't seem to find anyone that experienced the same thing.
Any idea?

Comment: I also get the same error

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had to use the `0.9.1` version of protobuf

```
plugins {
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.9.1"
}
```

Comment: That didn't help at all for me.

Comment: plugins{ id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.9.1"}
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.21.7"
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    "lite"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
--working for me, built successfully

Answer (score 4):

The configuration below worked for me.

At module's build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.9.1" 
}
dependencies {
    implementation  "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
    implementation  "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.18.0"
    ...
}
protobuf {
protoc {
    artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.21.7"
}

generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
        task.builtins {
            java {
                option 'lite'
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This was the solution for me as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
plugins { 
     id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.9.1"
}
```

....

```
protobuf {
        protoc {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.21.7"
        }
    
        generateProtoTasks {
            all().forEach { task ->
                task.builtins {
                    java {
                        "lite"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Try to build. Newer version of ProtoBuf